# Viscous stress equation in Newtonian fluid

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fluid-dynamics

In [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_fluid), it is said that for the incompressible isotropic case of Newtonian fluid, the viscous stress equation is

$$
\tau_{i j}=\mu\left(\frac{\partial v_{i}}{\partial x_{j}}+\frac{\partial v_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}\right)
$$
where

- $x_{j}$ is the $j$ th spatial coordinate
- $v_{i}$ is the fluid's velocity in the direction of axis $I$
- $\tau_{i j}$ is the $j$ th component of the stress acting on the faces of the fluid element perpendicular to axis $i$.

But I don't understand why there is a $\frac{\partial v_{j}}{\partial x_{i}}$ term here. It seems that $v_{j}$ penetrates the face, which means it can not provide sheer stress. Can anyone show me by graphs? Thank you!

Comment: My impression is that MO is not the suitable site. Have you looked at other sites of StackExchange ?

Comment: it's a symmetric tensor, which term contributes depends on the geometry.

Comment: The geometry is in the strain, not stress. Newtonian fluid assumption that stress is simply proportional to strain gives this relation for stress. The derivation of strain is in many textbooks. Basically you need to compute shear strain ( angle) as a function of velocity gradienta

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzaog118HUg) exactly solves my question.